# The Same Command Works Fine When Executed From Command Prompt

Tags: unix, zip

I am trying to create a csv file and zip it from a script. The first part works fine and abc.csv is created (assuming abc is the filename). I am able to see the file by navigating to the path.
After creating the file, I am trying to zip it using the below command

```
zip abc.zip abc.csv
```

I am getting the following error

```
zip warning: name not matched: abc.csv

zip error: Nothing to do! (abc.zip)
```

If I navigate to the path, I am able to execute `zip abc.zip abc.csv` without any issues.

Can you please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: believe the evidence (-; . If you **can** zip it after you `cd` into the correct directory, then your script needs to `cd /path/to/correct/directory` as well. Are you making the file like `csv_creating_cmd args file(s) > ./someotherdir/abc.csv`? then  you need to either pass the relative path to zip, `zip abc.zip ./someotherdir/abc.csv` or `cd ./someotherdir`. The same holds or `/full/path/to/data/`. Not really a programming question, voting to close. Good luck.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.